# Flutter : Prevent CachedNetworkImageProvider throwing when it cannot fetch the URL -- OR - How to convert between Image and ImageProvider

Tags: flutter, image, caching

Sometimes my image URLs are not available, or load fails for some other reason (like being offline).

When that happens my `CachedNetworkImageProvider` is throwing **SocketException: Failed host lookup**.

[image]

But I don't want it to throw, I just would like to see an empty placeholder there in that case (like the `Image` equivalent of a `Container()`).

- I can't use `CachedNetworkImage` (which has an error placeholder widget param) because an `ImageProvider` is required, rather than an `Image`.
- I can't use the `Image.image` parameter as the `CachedNetworkImage` doesn't support that.
- I've added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to my `AndroidManifest.xml` - that isn't the problem.
- I tried wrapping the widget in a try - catch, like the following but that doesn't do anything (ie. the throw still occurs and it never reaches the catch block):

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

cachedNetworkImageProviderThatDoesntCrash(String url) {
  try {
    return CachedNetworkImageProvider(url);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

- I tried extending `CachedNetworkImageProvider` but got stuck figuring out exactly what needed to be overriden.
- I tried cloning `CachedNetworkImageProvider` but then I need to add a whole bunch of other includes in my project ... it just was a very messy approach.

---

###### An easy solution would be if there was a way to wrap the `CachedNetworkImage` in something that converts it into a `CachedNetworkImageProvider`.

###### All I'm wanting to achieve is for the thing to not throw when there is any error loading the `CachedNetworkImageProvider` url.

### Update

I seem to hit this situation frequently - I realise it can be solved by a simple mechanism of converting between `Image` and `ImageProvider`, and visa versa, with the caveat that it would also work for `CachedNetworkImage` and `CachedNetworkImageProvider`.

Comment: so, why exactly cant you use the CachedNetworkImage and its `LoadingErrorWidgetBuilder` `errorWidget`?  where is an imageprovider needed? just supply the url and this errorbuilder, no?

Comment: It is because the image is being used as a background.  Here is my code:

```
Stack(
          children: [
            Opacity(
              opacity: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: cachedNetworkImageProviderThatDoesntCrash(appConfig.styles!.backgroundImageUrl!),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            childPage,
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Note: multi-line code formatting doesn't work in comments. If you need to show another piece of code then you might add another **Update** section to your post.

Comment: It's worth noting also that bounties are really to draw attention to a question, and perhaps to reward helpfulness. They are not really a device for free work, and thus noting an answer below as "not helpful enough" is not in the spirit of the site. Exercise kindness as much as you can.

Comment: okay, have you considered using a stack instead?

Comment: I was thinking about Isolates, maybe there's a way to completely prevent an Isolate from throwing error? In that case, you can call the function in an Isolate

Answer (score 2):

`Image` widget has an `errorBuilder` parameter.

You can use it to show placeholder images either from `network` or `asset` if an exception exists.

```
 Image(
        image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
          'htt://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
          errorListener: (p0) {
            debugPrint("errorListener: $p0");
          },
        ),
        errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
          // return const Image(
          //   image: AssetImage('assets/images/error_placeholder.jpg'),
          // ); // show placeholder from asset 

          return Image.network(
              'https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1274627/screenshots/3390285/404-error-sad-boat-800x600.jpg'); 
          // show placeholder from the network.
        },
      ),
```

Comment: This looks like the right answer - I was very excited to try it - unfortunately, believe it or not, this also still throws :

```
════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════
The following Event$ object was thrown resolving an image frame:
  [object Event]

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
Image provider: CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://blahblah.com/img.jpg", scale: 1) 
 Image key: CachedNetworkImageProvider("hhttps://blahblah.com/img.jpg", scale: 1): CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://blahblah.com/img.jpg", scale: 1)
```

Comment: If you don't want any exception to be thrown, you should fork/clone the library and customize it as per your need, as answered by @ebenezer-undie.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the official **CachedNetworkImage** github repo [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image) and fork it. Then go to the path in this image and comment(or delete) the **rethrow** statement in that file.

[image]

Go to your pubspec.yaml file and import the CachedNetworkImage from your repository like so:

```
cached_network_image:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/your_github_username/flutter_cached_network_image.git
    ref: your_commit_id
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  It is a way to stop it from throwing.  But not really helpful enough to be bounty worthy.  Thanks @ebenezar

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom image provider that extends `CachedNetworkImageProvider`,
override the `load` method to handle errors and provide a default/fallback image. `fallbackImage` is an ImageProvider so it should work for `Image` and `CachedNetworkImage`.

```
class SafeCachedNetworkImageProvider extends CachedNetworkImageProvider {

  final ImageProvider? fallbackImage;

  SafeCachedNetworkImageProvider(String url, {this.fallbackImage}) : super(url);

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(
      CachedNetworkImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    try {
      return super.load(key, decode);
    } catch (e) {
      if (fallbackImage != null) {
        return fallbackImage!.load(fallbackImage!, decode);
      }
      // Emit an error through the ImageStream
      final errorCompleter = ErrorImageStreamCompleter();
      errorCompleter.setError(e, StackTrace.current);
      return errorCompleter;
    }
  }
}

class ErrorImageStreamCompleter extends ImageStreamCompleter {
  void setError(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    reportError(
      context: ErrorDescription('Error in ImageStreamCompleter'),
      exception: error,
      stack: stackTrace,
    );
  }
}
```

Use the SafeCachedNetworkImageProvider wherever you need the ImageProvider as shown below:

```
SafeCachedNetworkImageProvider(
      'https://someurl.com/image.jpg',
      fallbackImage: AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder.png'),
    );
```

In the above, we provide a `fallbackImage` if the main image url fails to load. If no fallbackImage is provided, the error will be reported to any listeners.

Ideally, the Image widget will not display anything if it encounters an error in its ImageProvider.

Comment: For those looking at this now, "load()" and "DecoderCallback" are deprecated. Use "loadImage()" and "ImageDecoderCallback" instead.